# Convert num [1:20, 1] in a row array

Tags: r

I have the folowing array in R:

```
structure(c(1.98139389065475e-08, 3.96278778130931e-08, 7.92557556261902e-08, 
1.58511511252372e-07, 3.17023022504761e-07, 6.3404604500949e-07, 
1.26809209001904e-06, 2.53618418003796e-06, 5.07236836007617e-06, 
1.01447367201518e-05, 2.02894734403047e-05, 4.05789468806074e-05, 
8.11578937612187e-05, 0.00450692446282339, 0.0331829332673235, 
0.0324267128112546, 0.536844723615457, 0.29007911330816, 0.0821356435493368, 
0.0206616530120613), dim = c(20L, 1L), dimnames = list(NULL, 
    "V1"))
```

I would like to convert it in

```
c(1.98139389065475e-08, 3.96278778130931e-08, 7.92557556261902e-08, 
1.58511511252372e-07, 3.17023022504761e-07, 6.3404604500949e-07, 
1.26809209001904e-06, 2.53618418003796e-06, 5.07236836007617e-06, 
1.01447367201518e-05, 2.02894734403047e-05, 4.05789468806074e-05, 
8.11578937612187e-05, 0.00450692446282339, 0.0331829332673235, 
0.0324267128112546, 0.536844723615457, 0.29007911330816, 0.0821356435493368, 
0.0206616530120613)
```

It would suffice to copy C(...) as I did to write this question, but I'm wondering: is there a way to do this automatically, with statements in R?

Comment: If your original object is named `x`, then you can use `dput(c(x))` to get the actual code, or just `c(x)` to turn it into a vector. You could also use `as.vector` rather than `c` which is probably more appropriate but longer to type.

Comment: Maybe `data[,"V1"]`?

Comment: Or perhaps  `data[,1]`